# Переделать linq запрос в стандартную форму запроса

Tags: c#, linq

Есть такой запрос

```
internalStudents.Sort((x, y) => x.PersonData.CompareTo(y.PersonData as object));
```

И он работает прекрасно. Но пытаясь его переделать, обязательно нужно, не спрашивайте почему :D

```
internalStudents.Sort(from x in internalStudents
                                  from y in internalStudents
                                  select x.PersonData.CompareTo(y.PersonData as object);
```

В общем пытаюсь сделать так, но не канает.

Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" в "System.Collections.Generic.IComparer".    StudentsLabWork

```
private List<Student> internalStudents = new List<Student>();
```

сам код класса Student

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentsLabWork
{
    class Student
    {
        //закрытое поле типа Person, в котором хранятся данные студента
        private Person f_PersonData;
        //закрытое поле типа Education для информации о форме обучения;
        private Education f_Type;
        // закрытое поле типа int для номера группы;
        private int f_Group;
        // закрытое поле типа List<Exam> для информации об экзаменах, которые сдал студент.
        private List<Exam> f_Exams;
        // закрытое поле типа List<Test> для информации об экзаменах, которые сдал студент.
        private List<Test> f_Tests;

        //свойство типа Person для доступа к полю с данными студента;
        public Person PersonData
        {
            get
            {
                return f_PersonData;
            }
            set
            {
                f_PersonData = value;
            }
        }
        // свойство типа Education для доступа к полю с формой обучения;
        public Education Type
        {
            get
            {
                return f_Type;
            }
            set
            {
                f_Type = value;
            }
        }
        // свойство типа int для доступа к полю с номером группы;
        public int Group
        {
            get
            {
                return f_Group;
            }
            set
            {
                f_Group = value;
            }
        }
        // свойство типа List<Exam> для доступа к полю со списком экзаменов.
        public List<Exam> Exams
        {
            get
            {
                return f_Exams;
            }
            set
            {
                f_Exams = value;
            }
        }

        // свойство типа List<Test> для доступа к полю со списком экзаменов.
        public List<Test> Tests
        {
            get
            {
                return f_Tests;
            }
            set
            {
                f_Tests = value;
            }
        }



        //конструктор c параметрами типа Person, Education, int для инициализации соответствующих полей класса;

        public Student(Person _PersonData, Education _Type, int _Group)
        {
            f_PersonData = _PersonData;
            f_Type = _Type;
            f_Group = _Group;
        }
        // конструктор без параметров, инициализирующий поля класса значениями по умолчанию
        public Student() : this(new Person(), Education.Specialist, 0)
        {
            f_Exams = new List<Exam>();
            f_Tests = new List<Test>();
        }
        /*свойство типа double ( только с методом get), в котором вычисляется
          средний балл как среднее значение оценок в списке сданных экзаменов;*/
        public double Avg
        {
            get
            {
                double r = 0;
                if (f_Exams != null && f_Exams.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < f_Exams.Count; i++)
                        r += f_Exams[i].Mark;
                    r /= f_Exams.Count;
                }
                return r;
            }
        }

        /* индексатор булевского типа(только с методом get) с одним параметром
        типа Education; значение индексатора равно true, если значение поля с
        формой обучения студента совпадает со значением индекса, и false в
        противном случае;*/
        public bool this[Education t]
        {
            get
            {
                return t == f_Type;
            }
        }
        /*метод void AddExams(params Exam[] ) для добавления элементов в
        список экзаменов;*/
        public void AddExams(params Exam[] exams)
        {
            f_Exams = exams.ToList();
        }
        /* перегруженную версию виртуального метода string ToString() для
        формирования строки со значениями всех полей класса, включая список
        экзаменов и тестов;*/
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string ex = "";
            string tst = "";
            if (f_Exams != null && f_Exams.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < f_Exams.Count; i++)
                    ex += "\n" + f_Exams[i].ToString();
            }
            else
                ex = " нет";
            if (f_Tests != null && f_Tests.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < f_Tests.Count; i++)
                    tst += "\n" + f_Tests[i].ToString();
            }
            else
                tst = " нет";

            return String.Format("Форма обучения {1}\nГруппа {2}\nЭкзамены:{3}\nЗачеты:{4}",
                                   f_PersonData.ToString(), f_Type, f_Group, ex, tst);
        }
        /* виртуальный метод string ToShortString(), который формирует
        строку со значениями всех полей класса без списка экзаменов, но со значением среднего балла*/
        public virtual string ToShortString()
        {
            return String.Format("Форма обучения {1}\nГруппа {2}\nСредний балл: {3}",
                                   f_PersonData.ToString(), f_Type, f_Group, Avg);
        }
    }

}
```

Знаю что быдло код и т.д. Писал не я, а одногруппник. 
Помогите исправить ошибку

Comment: У вас не запрос, а вызов метода, соответственно его невозможно переделать во что-то другое в принципе

Comment: Вот если вы напишите linq-запрос с методом `OrderBy`, то его можно будет переделать в запрос с ключевым словом `orderby`.